# Upgrading devel version of statsmodels

Tags: python, python-2.7, statsmodels

I've got statsmodels 0.5.0 and I want to upgrade to the latest version which is 0.6.0.

So I do

```
$ git clone git://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels.git
$ cd statsmodels
$ pip install .
```

But, I get an error:

```
error: can't copy 'statsmodels/nonparametric/_smoothers_lowess.c': doesn't exist or not a regular file
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the solution is to install Cython (which I thought was already installed, or how could statsmodels 0.5.0 ever have worked in the first place..?!?).
Anyway, so it becomes:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels.git
$ cd statsmodels
$ pip install cython
$ pip install .
$ python
Python 2.7.3 |CUSTOM| (default, Apr 11 2012, 17:52:16) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import statsmodels
>>> statsmodels.version.full_version
'0.6.0.dev-b472807'
```

Comment: A release source distribution includes the generated c files, so cython is not necessary to install a release like 0.5.0. Installing from a source checkout requires cython.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I just noticed it actually says so on http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/install.html: "You will need a C compiler installed to build statsmodels. If you are building from the github source and not a source release, then you will also need Cython.".

So it is a case of RTFM I guess :-/